# Zend_Barcode::render() in CI framework - How to add text and other information before and after the rendered image

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello may someone please assist. I am trying out the zend barcode generator in code igniter. I have got it working. I am stuck where the page I am getting:
1. Is a black background, i want to change this background color, or maybe show the barcode in a table
2. I want to add text and other information on top of the generated barcode and under the barcode.
Please help.

```
public function index()
{
    //I'm just using rand() function for data example
    $temp = '57100-8Y6006578438628064';
    $this->set_barcode($temp);
}

private function set_barcode($code)
{
    //load library
    $this->load->library('zend');
    //load in folder Zend 
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    //generate barcode
    $file=Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());

}
```

}